# Why do move dialog can contain or not contain size information in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-transfer

Trying to investigate Windows copy problem, I found that file move dialogs can be absolutely different.

Here is an example. Sorry it is in Russian, so I translated some words in red:

[image]

You see, that upper dialog contains file size information while lower one does not. Both dialogs were called similarly by mouse dragging of some folders in windows explorer.

Moreover! After some time of working, upper dialog transformed itself into lower's version, i.e. it lost information about file sizes and remaining time and changed it's template accordingly.

**WHY???**

Comment: Please describe the difference in the files/folder being transfered.

Comment: Just different files. What difference you think can cause this?

Answer (score 0):

A possible explanation for the lower dialog could be that the total size was not known to the copy program. This can happen when a large number of small files is copied, because the system has to get the size of each file and this could be time consuming. You can notice this if you right click on a folder containing lots of small files and click Properties. The system needs some seconds to calculate the total size.

I find it harder to explain why the upper dialog suddenly turned into the second dialog, because the system was aware of the total size.